# I'm trying to find a book I read in the 70's about hive minds / psionics

Tags: story-identification, books, telepathy, psychic

Here's what I remember:

- The main character was a black girl (late teens or early 20's).
- I seem to recall the story takes place in California (maybe the Bay
  Area).
- The girl is the nexus of some sort of hive mind. She initially
  connects to six other psychics.
- The psychic powers the characters have include the ability to
  read/manipulate minds, heal, read psychic imprints from objects and
  telekinesis.
- The main antagonist is a sort of mental vampire. He feeds of the mind
  of his victim and takes over the body after he as fed.
- The antagonist bred the psychics because originally they "tasted
  better".
- The antagonist was originally from Egypt.
- The final conflict was won when the protagonist was able to add the
  antagonist into the hive mind, then drain him.

  Finally, I remember the cover had a girl's face on it with a triangle overlaying her face.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's Octavia Butler's [Patternist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patternist_series) series, probably the first one, *Patternmaster*.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patternmaster):

> *Patternmaster*, the first book to be published but the last in the series' internal chronology, depicts a distant future where the human race has been sharply divided into the dominant Patternists, their enemies the "diseased" and animalistic Clayarks, and the enslaved human mutes. The Patternists, bred for intelligence and psychic abilities, are networked telepaths. They are ruled by the most powerful telepath, known as the Patternmaster. Patternmaster tells the coming-of-age story of Teray, a young Patternist who learns he is a son of the Patternmaster. Teray fights for position within Patternist society and eventually for the role of Patternmaster.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking of the second book, "Mind of my Mind" but I'll read the whole series now.